# jQuery change css of given class within an id

Tags: jquery, css, find, ancestor

```
$('#slider1 .rangeslider__handle').css("border", "4px solid #99cc44");
```

That syntax doesn't work for changing the border of only that class within the given id.
I tried also

```
$.fn.hasAncestor = function(a) {
    return this.filter(function() {
        return !!$(this).closest(a).length;
    });
};
$('.rangeslider__handle').hasAncestor('#slider1').css("border", "4px solid #99cc44").change();
```

and

```
$('#slider1').find('.rangeslider__handle').css("border", "4px solid #99cc44");
```

Comment: `$('#slider1 .rangeslider__handle').css({"border", "4px solid #99cc44"});` watch the curly brackets

Comment: Is this script executing after the element is created or is the element created dynamically? An easy way to check if you are actually selecting anything at all is just use the JavaScript console in the browser developer tools. Just type in the select part `$('#slider1 .rangeslider__handle')` and the console should print the jQuery result.

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/nm069xhz/4/

Comment: @Psi: His code was correct without curly brackets. But if you want to use curly bracket (usefull for more than one CSS attribute change), you have you use `:` instead of a coma between the attribute and the value. ;)

Comment: Oh, true, that's a mistake. Of course you need a colon. I was not aware of that notation in $.css

Comment: Thanks all, still an issue. The following works:

$('.rangeslider__handle').css("border", "4px solid #99cc44");

but this does not when I add the id before :
$('#slider1 .rangeslider__handle').css("border", "4px solid #99cc44");

The only difference I see from your example, Barmar, is that my class is only present in CSS declaration file.

Comment: and this is slider1: <input type="range" name="count" id="slider1" value="1" min="1" max="'+totalSlides+'" >

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the plugin named ["Range Slider"](http://rangeslider.js.org/).

You certainly noticed that plugins creates new elements to achieve the nice visual effect, since your are after the element which has the `.rangeslider__handle` class.

This element is `div` child of another `div` which has the `.rangeslider` class.
And this one is the next sibling of the `input type="range"` from your initial HTML.

So, to target the handle starting for your input `id`, you can use `.next()` then `.find()` as in the below snippet.

I have placed the function on a button for clarity... and fun.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var sliderValueShow = $("#showValue");
     
  $('#slider1').rangeslider({
    polyfill: false,
    onSlide: function(position, value) {
      sliderValueShow.html(value);
    },
    onSlideEnd: function(position, value) {
      sliderValueShow.html(value);
    }
  });

  // Change the handle border color
  $("#setColor").click(function(){
    $('#slider1').next().find('.rangeslider__handle').css("border", "4px solid #99cc44");
  });
});
```

```css
#main{
  text-align:center;
  padding:20px;
}
#showValue{
  font-size:3em;
}
button{
  border-radius:10px;
  background-color:cyan;
  padding:6px;
  outline:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rangeslider.js/2.3.0/rangeslider.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rangeslider.js/2.3.0/rangeslider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div id="main">
  <input type="range" name="count" id="slider1" value="4" min="1" max="10"><br>
  <br>
  <span id="showValue">4</span><br>
  <br>
  <button id="setColor">Click me to change the handle border color</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you Louys, yes that works perfectly

Comment: I get this message now, but when the system lets me I will again: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: lol... I didn't knew this restriction about VOTING was also applied on answers to your own questions. So I upvoted you... ;) You still miss 6 points... Keep on using SO and your rep will increase. Now, I'm sure that you can ACCEPT the answer. Look for the check mark near the voting arrows.

Comment: Yes I accepted, thanks for letting me know about that too. I have the following question here outstanding for the last 3 days, nobody has replied, maybe you have time? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42587578/jquery-fade-in-out-and-delay-cancelling-previous-animation